# Blogger Recent Posts widget image Resize /s72-c

Tags: blogger

I am using this code to show Recent Posts on my blogger

```html
function showrecentpostswiththumbs(json){document.write('<ul class="recent_posts_with_thumbs">');for(var i=0;i<numposts;i++){var entry=json.feed.entry[i];var posttitle=entry.title.$t;var posturl;if(i==json.feed.entry.length)break;for(var k=0;k<entry.link.length;k++){if(entry.link[k].rel=='replies'&&entry.link[k].type=='text/html'){var commenttext=entry.link[k].title;var commenturl=entry.link[k].href;}
if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate'){posturl=entry.link[k].href;break;}}var thumburl;try{thumburl=entry.media$thumbnail.url;}catch(error)
{s=entry.content.$t;a=s.indexOf("<img");b=s.indexOf("src=\"",a);c=s.indexOf("\"",b+5);d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);if((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!="")){thumburl=d;}else thumburl='';}
var postdate=entry.published.$t;var cdyear=postdate.substring(0,4);var cdmonth=postdate.substring(5,7);var cdday=postdate.substring(8,10);var monthnames=new Array();monthnames[1]="Jan";monthnames[2]="Feb";monthnames[3]="Mar";monthnames[4]="Apr";monthnames[5]="May";monthnames[6]="Jun";monthnames[7]="Jul";monthnames[8]="Aug";monthnames[9]="Sep";monthnames[10]="Oct";monthnames[11]="Nov";monthnames[12]="Dec";document.write('<li class="clearfix">');if(showpostthumbnails==true)
document.write('<img class="recent_thumb" src="'+thumburl+'"/>');document.write('<b><a href="'+posturl+'" target ="_top">'+posttitle+'</a></b><br>');if("content"in entry){var postcontent=entry.content.$t;}
else
if("summary"in entry){var postcontent=entry.summary.$t;}
else var postcontent="";var re=/<\S[^>]*>/g;postcontent=postcontent.replace(re,"");if(showpostsummary==true){if(postcontent.length<numchars){document.write('<i>');document.write(postcontent);document.write('</i>');}
else{document.write('<i>');postcontent=postcontent.substring(0,numchars);var quoteEnd=postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");postcontent=postcontent.substring(0,quoteEnd);document.write(postcontent+'...');document.write('</i>');}}
var towrite='';var flag=0;document.write('<br><strong>');if(showpostdate==true){towrite=towrite+monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth,10)]+'-'+cdday+' - '+cdyear;flag=1;}
if(showcommentnum==true)
{if(flag==1){towrite=towrite+' | ';}
if(commenttext=='1 Comments')commenttext='1 Comment';if(commenttext=='0 Comments')commenttext='No Comments';commenttext='<a href="'+commenturl+'" target ="_top">'+commenttext+'</a>';towrite=towrite+commenttext;flag=1;;}
if(displaymore==true)
{if(flag==1)towrite=towrite+' | ';towrite=towrite+'<a href="'+posturl+'" class="url" target ="_top">More -></a>';flag=1;;}
document.write(towrite);document.write('</strong></li>');if(displayseparator==true)
if(i!=(numposts-1))
document.write('<hr size=0.5>');}document.write('</ul>');}
```

The problem is that The images have a really low resolution.. 
The link of the images contains s72-c, how can I change it to a higher quality?  
I will be happy if you can help me what should i need to change and how, sorry about my English and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default size of thumbnails is 72px squared, so you have to replace `/s72-c/` in thumbnail url with your size.

1- search for

`entry.media$thumbnail.url;`

2- replace it with

`entry.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72\-c\//,'/s300/');`

change 300 to your desired width.

**Snippet**

```html
<script>
  var numposts = 5,
      showpostthumbnails = true,
      showpostsummary = false,
      numchars = 0,
      showpostdate = false,
      showcommentnum = false,
      displaymore = false,
      displayseparator = true;
  
function showrecentpostswiththumbs(json) {
    document.write('<ul class="recent_posts_with_thumbs">');
    for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
        var posturl;
        if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
                var commenttext = entry.link[k].title;
                var commenturl = entry.link[k].href;
            }
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                posturl = entry.link[k].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        var thumburl;
        try {
            thumburl = entry.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72\-c\//,'/s300/');
        } catch (error) {
            s = entry.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                thumburl = d;
            } else thumburl = '';
        }
        var postdate = entry.published.$t;
        var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);
        var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);
        var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);
        var monthnames = new Array();
        monthnames[1] = "Jan";
        monthnames[2] = "Feb";
        monthnames[3] = "Mar";
        monthnames[4] = "Apr";
        monthnames[5] = "May";
        monthnames[6] = "Jun";
        monthnames[7] = "Jul";
        monthnames[8] = "Aug";
        monthnames[9] = "Sep";
        monthnames[10] = "Oct";
        monthnames[11] = "Nov";
        monthnames[12] = "Dec";
        document.write('<li class="clearfix">');
        if (showpostthumbnails == true)
            document.write('<img class="recent_thumb" src="' + thumburl + '"/>');
        document.write('<b><a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top">' + posttitle + '</a></b><br>');
        if ("content" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
        } else
        if ("summary" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
        } else var postcontent = "";
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");
        if (showpostsummary == true) {
            if (postcontent.length < numchars) {
                document.write('<i>');
                document.write(postcontent);
                document.write('</i>');
            } else {
                document.write('<i>');
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);
                var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                document.write(postcontent + '...');
                document.write('</i>');
            }
        }
        var towrite = '';
        var flag = 0;
        document.write('<br><strong>');
        if (showpostdate == true) {
            towrite = towrite + monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + '-' + cdday + ' - ' + cdyear;
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (showcommentnum == true) {
            if (flag == 1) {
                towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            }
            if (commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
            if (commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
            commenttext = '<a href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
            towrite = towrite + commenttext;
            flag = 1;;
        }
        if (displaymore == true) {
            if (flag == 1) towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            towrite = towrite + '<a href="' + posturl + '" class="url" target ="_top">More -></a>';
            flag = 1;;
        }
        document.write(towrite);
        document.write('</strong></li>');
        if (displayseparator == true)
            if (i != (numposts - 1))
                document.write('<hr size=0.5>');
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://levon-ltr.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentpostswiththumbs'></script>
```